# How to load a different image depending on the page content?

Tags: html, image, conditional-statements, src

I want to be able to have one image that loads into static html pages based on a conditional argument; so if X="something" then src="something.jpg", if X="another" then src="another.jpg" and so on.

I can't use a database.

So I am looking for some other technique or method that can use some kind of array and load one image from that array depending on something unique within the page.

I'm guessing that jQuery might do the job or maybe using XML/XSLT but I'm no programmer so any suggestions/guidelines/pointers will be gratefully received :)

Comment: Are these img tags for static images, maybe for a background image in a website layout? What is "X"? Is it a dynamic value from AJAX Callback, user interaction or is it available on page load (and will never change)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use jQuery, you can add the image once the DOM finishes loading.

Add a div tag in your html

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

and add the image with your logic using JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(){
 yourLogic = true;
    if (yourLogic){
        ('#test').prepend('<img id="imgId" src="path.png" />')
    }else{
        ('#test').prepend('<img id="imgId" src="someOtherPath.png" />')
    }
}
```